# MySQL - SELECT ... (Subquery) AS fieldname

Tags: mysql, sql, select, subquery

I currently have one MySQL table of posts for a forum. This includes parent posts and child posts. If it is a parent post, it has a `topic`. If it is a child post, it includes a `parent_id`.

E.g.:

```
TABLE posts

+----+-----------+---------+--------+------+
| id | parent_id |  topic  | author | body |
+----+-----------+---------+--------+------+
|  1 |      NULL | "Hello" |  "Me"  | ...  |
|  2 |         1 |  NULL   |  "Me"  | ...  |
+----+-----------+---------+--------+------+
```

I would like to run one SQL query, similar to the following:

```
SELECT id, 'self' AS parent_id, topic, author, body FROM posts WHERE parent_id IS NULL,
UNION
SELECT id, parent_id, (SELECT topic WHERE id=parent_id) as topic FROM posts WHERE topic IS NULL
```

Desired output:

```
+----+-----------+---------+--------+------+
| id | parent_id |  topic  | author | body |
+----+-----------+---------+--------+------+
|  1 |    "self" | "Hello" |  "Me"  | ...  |
|  2 |         1 | "Hello" |  "Me"  | ...  |
+----+-----------+---------+--------+------+
```

Basically, I want to return the parent topic without having to run multiple queries. Is there any way to do this? Should I just add a "parent_topic" field instead?

Thanks!

Comment: You can use case, `CASE WHEN parent_id IS NULL THEN 'self' ELSE parent_id END`.

Comment: My issue lies with returning the "topic" field from the parent post :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following SQL will do what you're looking for:

```
select p_child.id, if(p_child.parent_id is null, 'self', p_child.parent_id) as parent_id, if(p_parent.id is null, p_child.topic, p_parent.topic) as topic, p_child.author, p_child.body
from posts p_child
    left join posts p_parent on p_child.parent_id = p_parent.id;
```

Comment: Thanks! Had to finagle a bit to get it to fit my model (should have just used my model verbatim) but this did the trick! Any specific reason why you noted that a sub-query should be avoided?

Comment: For performance reasons, sub-queries should be avoided if at all possible (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577174/join-vs-sub-query for some discussion of the subject).

Answer (score 0):

Try this query, if the `parent_id is not null`, I am selecting the parents' `topic` in a sub-query. I am using `case` to do that.

```
SELECT id,
    CASE WHEN parent_id IS NULL THEN 'SELF'
         ELSE parent_id
    END as parent_id
    CASE WHEN parent_id IS NOT NULL THEN (SELECT t.topic FROM posts as t WHERE t.id = m.parenyt_id)
        ELSE topic
    END as Topic,
    author,
    body
FROM posts as m
```

Comment: A sub-query isn't required here, and should therefore be avoided.